# How to pass data to the website opened from android app

Tags: android

I Want to open a site from an app and pass data from that app to that website.Like if we open google page from my app,the searching word should be passed from the app which is nothing but auto-filling.Can anybody please suggest

Thanks,in advance

Comment: Some services have URL parameters you can add. Google for example has: `https://www.google.com/#q=test`

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to pass data from one app to an another app.
Go through this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html link for more info.

In your case, i guess implicit intents would be a better choice.